# Android - Reading HUGE (30MB) text files and compressing them

Tags: java, android, file, text, compression

I'm trying to read two files, join their contents and then GZIP it so I can send it to a server.

Everything works great when the files are a couple of MBs each but when one of them has weighs ~30MB (production expected size), while trying to read it I get an `Out of memory on a 43628012-byte allocation`error. I don't know what am I doing wrong, since it works great on smaller files.

Next is the code I use to read the text files:

```
    private String getTextFromFile(File fileName) {
        StringBuilder logsHolder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader input;
        try {
            input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line = null;
            String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null){
                logsHolder.append(line);
                logsHolder.append(lineSeparator);
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return logsHolder.toString();
    }
```

The error is launched on line `logsHolder.append(line);` after reading several thousands of lines. Next is the LogCat output:

```
            01-04 09:54:25.852: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1223K, 29% free 6002K/8364K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
            01-04 09:54:25.892: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1022K, 30% free 6235K/8860K, paused 16ms, total 17ms
            01-04 09:54:25.932: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 884K, 27% free 6481K/8860K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
            01-04 09:54:25.932: I/dalvikvm-heap(888): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.521MB for 1134874-byte allocation
            01-04 09:54:25.952: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 738K, 32% free 6851K/9972K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
            01-04 09:54:26.012: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 586K, 32% free 6851K/9972K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
            01-04 09:54:26.012: I/dalvikvm-heap(888): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.422MB for 1702306-byte allocation
            01-04 09:54:26.042: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1108K, 37% free 7405K/11636K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
            01-04 09:54:26.122: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 878K, 37% free 7405K/11636K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
            01-04 09:54:26.122: I/dalvikvm-heap(888): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.776MB for 2553454-byte allocation
            01-04 09:54:26.152: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 30% free 9899K/14132K, paused 10ms+2ms, total 27ms
            01-04 09:54:26.152: D/dalvikvm(888): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
            01-04 09:54:26.242: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2980K, 42% free 8236K/14132K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
            01-04 09:54:26.252: I/dalvikvm-heap(888): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.805MB for 3830176-byte allocation
            01-04 09:54:26.282: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 33% free 11977K/17876K, paused 10ms+3ms, total 27ms
            01-04 09:54:26.282: D/dalvikvm(888): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
            01-04 09:54:26.432: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4470K, 47% free 9483K/17876K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
            01-04 09:54:26.442: I/dalvikvm-heap(888): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.849MB for 5745260-byte allocation
            01-04 09:54:26.472: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 36% free 15094K/23488K, paused 17ms+2ms, total 33ms
            01-04 09:54:26.472: D/dalvikvm(888): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
            01-04 09:54:26.663: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6704K, 52% free 11353K/23488K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
            01-04 09:54:26.683: I/dalvikvm-heap(888): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.415MB for 8617886-byte allocation
            01-04 09:54:26.713: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 39% free 19769K/31904K, paused 17ms+2ms, total 32ms
            01-04 09:54:26.713: D/dalvikvm(888): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
            01-04 09:54:27.033: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10057K, 56% free 14158K/31904K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
            01-04 09:54:27.053: I/dalvikvm-heap(888): Grow heap (frag case) to 27.264MB for 12926824-byte allocation
            01-04 09:54:27.093: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8415K, 59% free 18366K/44528K, paused 17ms+2ms, total 32ms
            01-04 09:54:27.093: D/dalvikvm(888): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
            01-04 09:54:27.333: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4324K, 59% free 18367K/44528K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 29ms
            01-04 09:54:27.333: D/dalvikvm(888): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 22ms
            01-04 09:54:27.493: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2345K, 59% free 18366K/44528K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
            01-04 09:54:27.513: I/dalvikvm-heap(888): Grow heap (frag case) to 37.537MB for 19390232-byte allocation
            01-04 09:54:27.563: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 42% free 37302K/63464K, paused 34ms+4ms, total 51ms
            01-04 09:54:27.563: D/dalvikvm(888): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
            01-04 09:54:28.094: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20815K, 62% free 24678K/63464K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
            01-04 09:54:28.234: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1814K, 62% free 24678K/63464K, paused 22ms, total 23ms
            01-04 09:54:28.284: I/dalvikvm-heap(888): Grow heap (frag case) to 52.947MB for 29085344-byte allocation
            01-04 09:54:28.344: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 18935K, 63% free 34146K/91868K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
            01-04 09:54:29.245: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8191K, 63% free 34146K/91868K, paused 50ms, total 51ms
            01-04 09:54:29.846: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6821K, 63% free 34138K/91868K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
            01-04 09:54:29.846: I/dalvikvm-heap(888): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 43628012-byte allocation
            01-04 09:54:29.866: D/dalvikvm(888): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 76K, 63% free 34061K/91868K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
            01-04 09:54:29.866: E/dalvikvm-heap(888): Out of memory on a 43628012-byte allocation.
```

I don't know if the compressing part will work on such a big buffer, but for the time being, my only problem is with reading the huge text file.

I hope you can help me find why is this failing and what should I change to make it work.

**EDIT**

Next if the code I use to compress the joined content of both files:

```
        File previousLog = SystemEventsReceiver.getPreviousLog();
        if (previousLog.exists()) {
            logsHolder.append(getTextFromFile(previousLog));
        }

        File currentLog = SystemEventsReceiver.getCurrentLog();
        if (currentLog.exists()) {
            logsHolder.append(getTextFromFile(currentLog));
        }

        Log.v("MyApp", "uncompressed logs: " + logsHolder.toString().getBytes().length);
        // Compress logs.
        byte[] compressedLogs = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(logsHolder.length());
            GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(os);
            gos.write(logsHolder.toString().getBytes());
            gos.close();
            compressedLogs = os.toByteArray();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v("MyApp", "compressed logs: " + compressedLogs.length);
```

Comment: "I don't know what am I doing wrong, since it works great on smaller files" -- you are attempting to read the large file into memory, and you do not have enough memory to do so. "what should I change to make it work" -- find some way of accomplishing your aims that does not involve reading the entire file into memory.

Comment: @CommonsWare But why can't I load it into memory if it's only 30MB? I would understand if were speaking about XXXMB.

Comment: I'd try using IOUtils from Apache using a GZipOutputstream. Any appreach reading and/or writing the file as a whole into a String/memory is bound to fail.

Comment: Because you don't have a 30MB block of free heap space. The amount of heap space that your app has is very limited -- it could be as low as 16MB for the entire app, let alone any single allocation. Also, you are allocating 43,628,012 bytes, which is a bit larger than 30MB.

Comment: @PhilW I use `GZipOutputstream` to compress the joined content of both files. You say I should use it while reading them?

Comment: @PhilW I added the compress code that uses the `GZipOutputstream`. Could you give any examples of how to do it?

Comment: Exactly, I'd keep the GZipOutputstream open for both read operation blocks.
The idea is that you don't have more than a few kb in memory at any time. So you read into a buffer and then, before the next read, you write into the gzipoutputstream. IOUtils.copy() does this for you, I think. Just make sure it doesn't close the stream but make sure you close all streams when you're done.

Comment: @PhilW I answered the question myself trying to replicate your advice. Do you have any comments?

Comment: @Storo There are minor things you could change - you could look into try-with-resources / finally blocks but this is probably fine for your purposes.

Comment: @PhilW I can't use try-with-resources because I target devices that use API 16. Never heard of it so thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PhilW's comments, I came up with the following solution:

```
    Log.v("MyApp", "reading logs");
    // Get logs.
    File previousLog = SystemEventsReceiver.getPreviousLog();
    File currentLog = SystemEventsReceiver.getCurrentLog();

    int completeLogSize = (int) (currentLog.length() + previousLog.length());
    Log.v("MyApp", "uncompressed logs: " + completeLogSize);
    // Compress logs.
    byte[] compressedLogs = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(completeLogSize);
        GZIPOutputStream gzipOS = new GZIPOutputStream(os);

        if (previousLog.exists()) {
            addLogToGZIP(previousLog, gzipOS);
        }
        if (currentLog.exists()) {
            addLogToGZIP(currentLog, gzipOS);
        }

        gzipOS.close();
        compressedLogs = os.toByteArray();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.v("MyApp", "compressed logs: " + compressedLogs.length);



    private void addLogToGZIP(File logFile, GZIPOutputStream gzipOS) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        try {
            BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(logFile));
            while (buffer.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length) != -1) {
                gzipOS.write(bytes);
            }
            buffer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I read the bytes from each logfile and add it straight to the `GZIPOutputStream`.
It works great on 55MB files (~1.100.000 lines) and even on files of 100MB (~2.200.000 lines).